# Why is it called a "factored" import statement in golang?

Tags: go

I'm going through the "A Tour of Go" tutorial and got to [this lesson](https://tour.golang.org/basics/2) that states:

> This code groups the imports into a parenthesized, "factored" import statement.
>
> ```
> import (
>     "fmt"
>     "math"
> )
> ```
>
> You can also write multiple import statements, like:
>
> `import "fmt"`
>
> `import "math"`
>
> But it is good style to use the factored import statement.

Does anyone know why this format is called a "factored" import statement? What about that format makes it "factored"? I've never heard that word used that way before.

Comment: Maybe it's like in math, where you can "factor" `x * a + x * b` to `x * (a + b)` - now replace `x` with `import`, `a` with `fmt` and `b` with `math`...? ;)

Comment: I had a similar first guess, and when you lay it out like that it does seem plausible. Still just seems like a stretch of that word and not worth the confusion. Why not just "multi-line import" statement?

Comment: They wanted to define a term, and "factored" is the term they chose. You would have to ask them—the authors of this particular part of the tutorial—why they chose that particular word, to get anything definitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comments under the question are correct according to the documentation. See this example from [docs](https://golang.org/src/cmd/go/alldocs.go?h=factored#L1770) as a good indication:

```
// The leading verb can be factored out of adjacent lines to create a block,
// like in Go imports:

    require (
        new/thing v2.3.4
        old/thing v1.2.3
    )
```

The comment clearly specifies `"require"`, a shared "verb", as being factored out. That is, instead of writing two lines with the word `require`, you can take it back and use parenthesis to indicate all lines in the block share this initial "verb". This is the same as `ab+ac=a(b+c)`, which is called factoring. I think this is indication enough for the choice of wording, a good one in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the following issue  https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24011, "factored import" is not a formal term used in golang specification.

The go-tour developer would have come up with that term to differentiate it from the regular import statement.

Having said that, we dont need to break our sweat on the option to choose, you can stick to the coding convention followed in your team (or stick to once option consistently across your code base)